# Problem with saving new elements in my xml at right level

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

I have a xml file that looks like this:

```
<DataTalk> 
<Posts> 
<TalkPost>
<PostType>dialog</PostType>
        <User>ABBE</User>
        <Customer>HRM - Heroma</Customer>
        <PostedDate>0001-01-01T00:00:00</PostedDate>
        <Message>TEST</Message> 
</TalkPost> 
</Posts>
</DataTalk>
```

When I now want to save new  elements, I do:

```
    document.root.add((new XElement("TalkPost", new XElement("PostType", newDialog.PostType), 
new XElement("User", newDialog.User), new XElement("Customer", newDialog.Customer),
new XElement("PostedDate", newDialog.PostDate), new XElement("Message", newDialog.Message)));
```

The problem is now that it gets saved at the wrong hierarchal level. They all gets saved under `<datatalk>` and not under `<posts>` that I wan't to. How should I do to save the new elements under the `<posts>` hierarchically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.Root.Element("Posts").Add(new XElement("TalkPost", ...));` should do.